# Error using Textfield and charfield model in Django

Tags: python, django, model, textfield

I have been trying to use Textfield in class but the suggestions just does not show up. Instead i receive an error in my Cmd console. This was even the case while using CharField.

Below is my code:

```
from django.db import models 
from django.db.models import CharField
from django.db.models import Textfield

from datetime import datetime

class Posts(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  body = models.TextField()
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

> This is the error i get in my CMD:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\python\python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "d:\python\python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 
109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in 
raise_last_exception
raise _exception[1]
File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in 
execute
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
app_config.import_models()
File "C:\Users\USER\Envs\py1\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "d:\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "E:\Python\djangoproject\posts\models.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.db.models import Textfield
ImportError: cannot import name 'Textfield' from 'django.db.models' (C:\Users\USER\Envs\py1\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\__init__.py)
```

Comment: You imported `Textfield` (without a capital `F`), it should be `from django.db.models import TextField`.

Comment: o great.. thanx.... but why do i have to import all the models seperately? Is there a way i can import all the models at once? ie I had to import seperately for Charfield and Textfield.. Thanx for the solution

Comment: you don't. You can import it as `from django.db.models import CharField, TextField`. These are btw *not* models, but model fields.

Comment: Thanx a lot for the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need to import the fields separately, you could use the django.db.models that you have imported earlier.

And the error is produced because you should use `TextField` with a capital `F`

Comment: Great.. I tried running the server without importing separately..it worked! . but should it be suggesting me the model fields?

Comment: I guess that depends mainly on the editor that you are using.